# Sign in with Google Button for Sign Up

Tags: login, google

Our app will use the Sign in with Google button for Sign up and Log in. After gathering information, the end result of the sign up is to log the user into a different area than the Log in button - which goes to a member area.

If a user click on the Sign Up button and it's detected they have already created an account, should we redirect them to the logged in member area or should we display an error telling them they already have created an account and provide a link for them to log in - triggering the Google auth process again? Is it expected behavior or is it a dark pattern to log them in, even if the button shows "Sign Up" and the button is suppose to create an account?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it make sense to authenticate a user when he/she provides existing valid credentials while registering?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78936/does-it-make-sense-to-authenticate-a-user-when-he-she-provides-existing-valid-cr)

Answer (score 1):

Google authentication is always used for signing in users. When a user clicks 'Sign in with Google', it will open the authentication popup, takes the credentials and signs in to the user. Since you are using Google authentication, it will always let the user log in and you can redirect them to the dashboard.

[image]